# Trying to open a activity from a fragment tab with 4 buttons in it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am building an app in which I have 3 fragment tabs. In the first tab I have 4 buttons, which will open 4 different activities, but when I try to launch a new activity on button's `onClick` my app crashes. I will post my code here for first fragment tab which has 4 buttons in it.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clienttab1, container, false);
        btn1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn4 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        addListenerOnButton();
        return rootView;
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity4.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: what does the logcat say??? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212969/how-to-ask-correctly-for-android-problems/212970#212970

Comment: could you post the exception ?

Comment: without logcat data it is difficult to say what is wrong with your code

Comment: oh ya i find the error thank you guys for reminding me about logcat :). i just saw that i did not declared my activity in manifest.xml its working perfectly now:D